# Could $\langle \Gamma | R \rangle \cong \langle \Gamma | S\rangle$ if $\langle R\rangle \subsetneq \langle S\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

If we have two *finitely presented* groups $\langle \Gamma | R\rangle$ and $\langle \Gamma | S\rangle$ with $\langle R\rangle \subsetneq \langle S\rangle$, could they be isomorphic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. An example is $\langle x,y \mid x \rangle$ and $\langle x,y \mid x,y^{-1}xy \rangle$.

Both presentations define an infinite cyclic group, but $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle x,y^{-1}xy \rangle$ are distinct subgroups of the free group on $x,y$. The first is cyclic and the second is free of rank $2$ on its generators.

Comment: Hum I think in your example $R=<x^2> = <x^2, x^4> = S$

Comment: Sorry I meant <R> = <S> (I think <S> is the subgroup generated by S, isn't it?)

Comment: OK, yes you are right, I will edit the answer!